# How can I update a nested array with ionic4 storage

Tags: ionic4, ionic-storage

Using

```
openSavedForm() {
  this.storage.get('test').then((val) => {
    this.auditResults = JSON.parse(val);
    this.audit = this.auditResults
    this.auditOne = this.auditResults.siteVehicle; 
    console.log('pull all', this.audit);     
  });
}
```

I can view my key value pair stored items in sqlite.  Here is a photo of the of the console.log

[image: console.log of db]

Is it possible to only update only the siteVehicle Array with

```
async saveFormUpdates() {
  this.newAudit =this.auditOne;
  await this.storage.set( 'test', JSON.stringify(this.newAudit));
  console.log ("storage", this.newAudit);
}
```

with out deleting all the other arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My async saveFormUpdates() was wrong.  Turns out just saving this.audit instead of this.auditOne did everything with no further input from me.

```
async saveFormUpdates() {
 this.newAudit = this.audit;
 await this.storage.set( 'test', JSON.stringify(this.newAudit));
 console.log ("storage", this.newAudit);
}
```